# No such namespace: sql

Tags: clojure, luminus, hugsql

I read Web Development with Clojure, 3rd Edition and got stuck at:

```
; Jack-in done.
clj꞉user꞉> (in-ns 'guestbook.db.core)
#namespace[guestbook.db.core]
clj꞉guestbook.db.core꞉> 
(conman/bind-connection *db* "sql/queries.sql")
; Syntax error compiling at (.calva/output-window/output.calva-repl:1:8039).
; No such namespace: sql
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: ...are you sure that code you posted is **exactly** what you put in your REPL?

Comment: The error message is misleading. It looks like there is something wrong with the argument "sql/queries.sql". But this is not the problem. The problem is that something is wrong with your require statements. See in `reporting-example/src/clj/reporting_example/db/core.clj`! There is a require for `[next.jdbc.sql :as sql]`. For some reason you don't have this in your namespace. It is hard to give you more support here. Please provide more context, so that we can understand the problem. I think, there is something, which you have forgotten to load.